# Unable to replace onreadystate to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-browser

I was hiding the loading icon when my file finished downloading in an `iframe`. It was working fine in Internet Explorer. In Chrome I was unable to make it wait until the file loads in the `iframe`.

Any help is appreciated.

```
function checkIframeLoaded() {
    var iFrameObject = document.getElementById("iframehidden");
    var iframeDoc = iFrameObject.contentDocument || iFrameObject.contentWindow.document;
    if (iframeDoc.readyState == 'complete' || iframeDoc.readyState == "interactive" || iframeDoc.readyState == "loaded") {
        if (top.document.getElementById("tblPleaseWait") != null) {
            top.document.getElementById("tblPleaseWait").style.display = "none";
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("tblPleaseWait") != null) {
            document.getElementById("tblPleaseWait").style.display = "none";
        }
        return;
    }
}

function setupLoader(objIFrame, brestorepane) {
    if (objIFrame.attachEvent) {
        if (brestorepane) {
            objIFrame.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', checkIframeLoaded);
        }

    } else {
        if (brestorepane) {
            objIFrame.addEventListener('load', checkIframeLoaded()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting up the handler incorrectly in non-IE browsers.

First, there's a typo. `addEventListner` should be `addEventListener`. Your [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) might have mentioned this.

After that, you're *calling* `checkIframeLoaded()` immediately, rather than referencing it as a handler.

Try:

```
objIFrame.addEventListener('load', checkIframeLoaded);
```

Comment: yea its a typo, but load is not helping to wait until objIFrame is loaded

Comment: So after fixing both issues, the problem persists? You should edit the question with the updated code, or you'll get more answers just telling you to fix those two problems.

Comment: Noting that only the `addEventListener` typo was fixed; you're still calling `checkIframeLoaded()` when you don't mean to. I'm still curious what happens when you remove the parentheses, as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the `iframe src` points to content on your own site and you've properly set `allow-same-origin` then you can use this method (you tagged question with jQuery, so this solution uses jQuery, but pure JS alternative is possible as well)

```js
function checkIframeLoaded() {
  if (top.document.getElementById("tblPleaseWait") != null) {
    top.document.getElementById("tblPleaseWait").style.display = "none";
  } else if (document.getElementById("tblPleaseWait") != null) {
    document.getElementById("tblPleaseWait").style.display = "none";
  }
}
$("#iframehidden").on("load", checkIframeLoaded);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='tblPleaseWait'>PLEASE WAIT</div>
<iframe id='iframehidden' name='iframehidden' src='http://stacksnippets.net' style='border:2px solid #ccc;'></iframe>
```

Another way you can do this is to put the code into the `iframe` document itself (such as `iframe.html`):

```
$(window).on("load", function()
{
   var plsWait = top.document.getElementById("tblPleaseWait");
   if(plsWait) plsWait.style.display = "none";
});
```

If the `iframe src` is on somebody else's site - then you are in trouble. Unless the remote content has been set to allow cross site scripting.

Also, as Paul Roub pointed out, you have an error here:

`objIFrame.addEventListener('load', checkIframeLoaded());`

You are not actually delegating the `checkIframeLoaded` function to the `load` event; you are executing that function with the parenthesis `()` and instead delegating its result, which is `undefined`.

Simply remove the parenthesis to achieve the desired effect, which is that `checkIframeLoaded` will be called when the `load` event is triggered:

`objIFrame.addEventListener('load', checkIframeLoaded);`

After that you just need to work within the constraints of scripting across frames.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function checkIframeLoaded() {
  if (top.document.getElementById("tblPleaseWait") != null) {
    top.document.getElementById("tblPleaseWait").style.display = "none";
  } else if (document.getElementById("tblPleaseWait") != null) {
    document.getElementById("tblPleaseWait").style.display = "none";
  }
}
$("#iframehidden").on("load", checkIframeLoaded);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='tblPleaseWait'>PLEASE WAIT</div>
<iframe id='iframehidden' name='iframehidden' src='http://stacksnippets.net' style='border:2px solid #ccc;'></iframe>
```